# Docker and Flask project refresh on file change

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a running docker image for my project: Flask with Apache WSGI.

How can I start the container with the local path of my project and when I change something on the code to apply direct to the container? I have tried in this way:

```
docker run -p 81:80 -d -v /local/project/path --name container-name image-name
```

But after I change something in my editor the change doesn't apply.
Is the way I start the container right and should be there some option to reload the Apache web server because it is caching everything.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:10

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER name

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 \
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
build-essential \
python3 \
python3-dev\
python3-pip \
vim \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get autoremove \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy over and install the requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /var/www/home/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /var/www/home/requirements.txt

# Copy over the apache configuration file and enable the site
COPY ./configs/apache-flask.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/apache-flask.conf
RUN a2ensite apache-flask
RUN a2enmod headers

# Copy the code
COPY ./service /var/www/home/

RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN a2ensite apache-flask.conf

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /var/www/home

CMD  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

my WSGI Apache conf

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

  # Python application integration
  WSGIDaemonProcess /apache-flask processes=4 threads=20 python-path=/var/www/home/:/usr/bin/python3:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3.7/
  WSGIProcessGroup /apache-flask
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/home/ws.wsgi

  <Directory "/var/www/home/">
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      WSGIProcessGroup /apache-flask
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      Options +ExecCGI
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: I'd recommend using Flask's dev server and an ordinary Python virtual environment (and no Docker) for day-to-day development.  When you need to do integration testing or deployment, re-run `docker build` to get a new image.  I wouldn't recommend using the `docker run -v` option to overwrite the image's code with something else.

Comment: What are the advantages of the dev server to docker?

Comment: It _is_ a local development environment; you're not trying to simulate one by working around Docker's filesystem isolation features.  You can use ordinary IDEs and Python tooling without having to cross the Docker boundary (and without requiring administrator privileges).  You probably have Python installed already.

Comment: Yes, but when many developers are working on the same project, then we need to have some standard at the versions. Some of them are working on Mac other to Linux or Windows. We can not be expecting, that each one has the same versions like the other.

Answer (score 0):

To reload the webserver I have added in the WSGI config:

```
WSGIScriptReloading On
```

To update the code in the container on changes from the editor I have to change the volume parameter in this way:

```
docker run -p 81:80 -d -v /local/project/path:/var/www/home/ --name container-name image-name
```

I was starting the container without telling him, where to mount the files.

Now everything works fine!